# Installing Nginx on Linux Error

Tags: linux, nginx, yum

I am trying to install Nginx on my Linux EC2 server and following the [nginx guide](https://www.nginx.com/blog/setting-up-nginx/), but I run into an issue at `sudo apt-key add nginx_signing.key` because I believe `apt-key add` is an Ubuntu command while Linux uses `yum`? I tried running the command and get `sudo: apt-key: command not found`.

Then I tried `sudo yum add nginx_signing.key` and received `Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper No such command: add. Please use /usr/bin/yum --help`

Finally I tried `sudo yum install nginx_signing.key` and received `No package nginx_signing.key available.`

What is the proper command to run on the Linux server to get Nginx up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are apparently using RHEL, CentOS or Fedora, you will need to import the key using the RPM package manager:

```
rpm --import /path/to/nginx_signing.key
```

or directly from NGINX with:

```
rpm --import http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key
```